# Get file name in Tkinter and display it after chosing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

programm should create a window, put a button in centr. when a button pressed opened a system window where a file need to be chosen, and after that, a file name should be written under the button. I got problems with the last part, file name displays only on console, tried to get `filename` out of function, but I get an error.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.constants import CENTER
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me',command=UploadAction, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)
button1.place (relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5, anchor=CENTER)
canvas1.create_text(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.7, anchor=CENTER, text= filename, fill="black", font=('Helvetica 15 bold'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One solution make `filename` as global (source: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp)

Comment: `button1.place(...)` should not be executed after you have put `button1` inside the canvas using `canvas1.create_window(...)`.  Also `filename` is undefined when `canvas1.create_text(..., text=filename, ...)` is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to display text on a canvas, but there's an easier way using a label and changing its text:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filename = None
def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)
    # Change text of label
    label1['text'] = filename

root= tk.Tk()
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me', command=UploadAction, bg='brown', fg='white')
button1.pack(padx=2, pady=5)
label1 = tk.Label(text='Please choose a file')
label1.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to display just the filename:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filename = None
def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = askopenfilename()
    # Cut path to the file off
    filename = filename.split('/')[len(filename.split('/'))-1]
    print('Selected:', filename)
    label1['text'] = filename

root= tk.Tk()
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me', command=UploadAction, bg='brown', fg='white')
button1.pack(padx=2, pady=5)
label1 = tk.Label(text='Please choose a file')
label1.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

root.mainloop()
```